# Propagating a by-name parameter to a function call

Tags: scala

Inside the body of a function that has a "By-name" parameter "f", I want to call another function and pass that parameter inside it. Specifically, I want to pass a "block" of code inside my `timeit` function:

```
def warmUpAndMeasure(f: =>Int) = {
  val minimumTimeTaken = common.utils.timeit(
    repeat = 20, 
    assertResult = Some(148848)) {
      f
    }
  println(s"Best execution took $minimumTimeTaken ms.")
}
warmUpAndMeasure { antFunctional.funcs.walk(1000,1000) }
```

Starting from the last line of the code, I call `warmUpAndMeasure` passing inside it a code block. `warmUpAndMeasure` is in turn supposed to pass that block into `common.utils.timeit`, but setting it up first so that it will repeatedly (20 times) call the passed in code block, verifying that each time it returns 148848, and reporting at the end, the minimum time taken to execute the block (out of all 20 times).

I am new to Scala, and so far, the only way I've found out to pass `f` as-is into `timeit` (and not call it!) - as you can see in the code above - is to write another nameless code block: `{ f }`. Is there any other way to specify that I want `f` to pass in, not be called at the invocation of `timeit`?

**EDIT**: Clarifying - my code above works, but I am just asking whether there's a better way to "delay the evaluation" of parameter `f` other than writing another block (as I did). Here's the code for my `timeit`, for reference:

```
def timeit[A](repeat:Int=20, assertResult:Option[A] = None)(f: => A) = {
  val minimumTime = List.range(1,repeat+1).map {
    idx => {
      if (idx == 1)
        print("Benchmark iteration:     ")
      print("\b\b\b\b%4d" format idx)
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val result = f
      var totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis - startTime
      assertResult match {
        case Some(value) => {
          try { assert(value == result) }
          catch { case e:AssertionError =>
            println("\nExpected:" + value + ", got:" + result) ; throw e
          }
        }
        case None => ()
      }
      totalTime
    }
  }.min
  print("\n")
  minimumTime
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, it's very confused. What is the definition of `timeit`? In Scala, function definitions define if a parameter is passed by value or by name, if you want to call `timeit` with `f` without evaluating it, then you need to make sure `timeit` accepts this parameter by name.

Comment: If your `timeit` accepts a by-name parameter then won't it just work as such? (I find by-name parameters confusing and prefer to use an explicitly lazy type like `()=>Int`, which always works as you expect)

Comment: @vptheron: I added the code for `timeit` to the post - and let me clarify: my code works, I just want to make sure that I am not missing some better syntax for "delaying the evaluation" of parameter `f` when invoking `timeit`.

Comment: @lmm: I am very interested to see the alternative syntax you'd use - I am new to Scala, and in this case, I am basically investigating passing "code blocks" to a function - and don't know how the caller would look if `f` wasn't a by-name parameter...

Comment: The downside is you have to construct the code block explicitly, like `{() => performComputation()}`. I take an "explicit is better than implicit" view, but I can understand why people prefer the conciseness of a by-name parameter.

Comment: @ttsiodras Thanks. I don't think you're missing anything. You could use parentheses instead of curly braces when calling `timeit` but that's it.You could use a function with 0 parameters like @lmm suggests but then the syntax to call the function may get awkward/verbose.

Comment: @lmm: Indeed, I am one of those people that prefer it - I love how the caller syntax feels "native" :-)

Comment: @vptheron: Using parens - I missed that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the only thing I was missing was that I can pass `f` inside parentheses (thanks, @vptheron).

```
common.utils.timeit(repeat = 20, assertResult = Some(148848))(f)
```